# Como guardar en una variable string un texto proveniente de un archivo externo .txt?

Tags: java, io

Hola a todos soy muy novato en el mundo de Java y tengo un pequeño problema, actualmente quiero guardar en una variable String un texto proveniente de un archivo .txt, pero con los escasos conocimientos que tengo de Java hice algo muy rudimentario que ademas no funciona bien porque al leer la variable "texto" que es donde almaceno la informacion del .txt me muestra lo siguiente: "nullEsto es una prueba".

(Esto es una prueba) es el contenido del txt.

Espero que algun sabio me pueda ayudar muchas gracias de antemano.

```
public class Acceso_fichero {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Leer_fichero accediendo=new Leer_fichero();
        accediendo.lee();
    }
}

class Leer_fichero{

    String texto;

    public void lee() {

        try {
            FileReader entrada=new FileReader("C:/Users/Etchko/Desktop/leeme.txt");

                int c=0;

                while(c!=-1) {
                    c=entrada.read();

                    char letra=(char)c;

                    texto+=letra;
                }

                entrada.close();

                System.out.println(texto);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("No se ha encontrado el archivo");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instancia la variable texto = "" `String texto = "";` :)

Comment: Ademas revisa BufferedReader, te sera mas util para lo que quieres. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas chicos creo que definitivamente deberia revisar lo del BufferedReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inicializa tu variable **texto**, porque por default cualquier Objeto no inicializado le asigna **null** ¿Por qué?. Porque **String** es un objeto ya que extiende de [java.lang.Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) y al no inicializarlo le asigna null. No es como los primitivos por ejemplo en el caso de los int que sino lo inicializas le asigna un **0**  .De tal manera que cuando haces el primer texto+=letra; contcatena **null** y **E**. Tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Acceso_fichero {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Leer_fichero accediendo=new Leer_fichero();
        accediendo.lee();
    }
}

class Leer_fichero{

    String texto="";

    public void lee() {

        try {
            FileReader entrada=new FileReader("C:/properties/leeme.txt");

                int c=0;

                while(c!=-1) {
                    c=entrada.read();

                    char letra=(char)c;

                    texto+=letra;
                }

                entrada.close();

                System.out.println(texto);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("No se ha encontrado el archivo");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta clase ***"FileReader***" tiene métodos que nos permiten leer caracteres.

***"FileReader"*** no contiene métodos que nos permitan leer líneas completas ( a veces se requiere de ello), 
 pero ***"BufferedReader"*** se puede construir un ***"BufferedReader"*** a partir del ***"FileReader"*** como te lo muestro en acá:

```
        /*Incio del fichero y creación de BufferedReader para poder
         ** lectura (disponer del metodo readLine())*/

        File archivo = new File("C:\\Users\\Etchko\\Desktop\\leeme.txt");
        FileReader entrada = new FileReader(archivo);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(entrada);
```

La forma de leerlo sería está:

```
while((texto=br.readLine())!=null)
```

Acá podes realizar lo que desees dentro del ciclo y la forma de recorrerlo es más sencilla.

Te comparto tu código con algunas modificaciones con lo que te mencionaba antes, para que lo probes y veas que es mejor implementarlo así:

```
public class Acceso_fichero {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Leer_fichero.lee();
    }
}

class Leer_fichero{



    public static void lee() {
        String texto = "";
        try {
            /*Incio del fichero y creación de BufferedReader para poder
             ** lectura (disponer del metodo readLine())*/
            File archivo = new File("C:\\Users\\Etchko\\Desktop\\leeme.txt");
            FileReader entrada = new FileReader(archivo);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(entrada);

            /*Leer Fichero*/
         while((texto=br.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(texto);
         }
            entrada.close();

            } 
        catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("No se ha encontrado el archivo:" + e.getMessage());
            }
    }
}
```

Suerte...